# RubyOnRails Unauthorised Host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m just wondering if anyone could help me fix the following error that it presented by rubyonrails:

`To allow requests to domain.tld, add the following to your environment configuration: config.hosts << "domain.tld"`

Cheers!
P.S. I’m new to ruby and ruby-on-rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one line – as told in the message – to the file that configures the environment in which you want to use that domain.

For example, when you want to use the `domain.tld` in your development environment then add the following line to your `config/environments/development.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ... existing config

  config.hosts << "domain.tld"  # <= Add this line
end
```

Please note: After changing the configuration of your application you need to restart the server.